# Golang remove file not return error but file still exist in Windows

Tags: windows, file, go

I write a golang program in Windows which remove old file then create new file. New file has same name as old file.

```
if err := os.Remove("abc.txt"); err != nil {
    return err
}

file, err := os.OpenFile("abc.txt", os.O_EXCL|os.O_CREATE, 0600)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

But I got error

> OpenFile error, myfile is exist

When I check abc.txt is still the old file